# Back button giving error message on login page

Tags: php

So I made a login page for our users to manage their accounts, and once logged in it takes them to a user control panel type page. Once they're on that page they can see all the other pages that are available to them. If they click on Page 2 for example, and then press the back button(which would bring them back to that user control panel) they get an error message saying:

Firefox - Document Expired
          This document is no longer available.
Chrome - Confirm Form Resubmission

IE - Document Expired

If however they go to page 2 and then from page 2 to page 3 and hit the back button, it will bring them back to page 2 without any issue. I hope this makes sense, and thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: This is because you are sending them back to your login submit. It can be missed if you after login redirects them to the same page.

Comment: I would just use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] as the back button location. This will put you back to where you came from while also reloading the new page (which is what is causing that Expire error, you are resending data)

Comment: I mean back button as in the browsers back button.